# How to calculate area of a polygon drawn on map in pixels?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a polygon with an approximate area of 10 000 m2
I'm trying to determine on which zoom level the polygon became almost invisible, means - the number of pixels it takes to draw the polygon is negligible, and remove it from map to save resources.
Since I already have a real polygon area value, how can I calculate the area of a polygon drawn on a map, in pixels, for specific zoom level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to simplify the problem I'd suggest working with the polygon's bounds rather than the polygon itself. That way you always deal with a rectangle and avoid the trouble of calculating sizes of irregular polygons.
With that in mind, and assuming your polygon is simple and has only one path, you could do something like this:

```
var points = poly.getPath();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var n = 0; n < points.length ;n++){
    bounds.extend(points[n]);
}
var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();
var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();

var proj = map.getProjection();
var swPx = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(SW);
var nePx = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(NE);
var pixelWidth = (nePx.x - swPx.x)* Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
var pixelHeight = (nePx.y - swPx.y)* Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
```

Comment: Looks like "Math.pow(2, map.getZoom())" part is redundant here, since (nePx.x - swPx.x) already gives us the boundary rectangle width

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo, but I'm looking for a more generic way. I think polygon and it's boundary area both are just a function of a current zoom level. What we need here is a simple expression involving a zoom

Comment: The method fromLatLngToPoint() gives you "World coordinates".After you got that you need to take the zoom level into account. Explained here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#WorldCoordinates

Comment: What do you think about this?
<code>   
screen_area = real_area/Math.pow(4, 17-zoom);</code>
Where real_zoom can be calculated with google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(poly.getPath())

Answer (score 2):

Version with the polygon and not the bounds, google maps:

```
var square_meters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(yourPolygon.getPath());

var init_resolution = 256 / (2 * Math.PI * 6378137);

var zoom = map.getZoom();

var resolution = init_resolution * Math.pow(2,zoom);

var area_factor = Math.pow(resolution,2);
var square_pixels = square_meters * area_factor;
```

`256` is the `TileSize` of the map and `6378137` the radius of the earth in meters. You get the area of your polygon in squared pixels. You can compare this to your maps dimensions in squared pixels (`height * length` of `div`);